# reactjs html get request not received by php

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs

I have written a webpage that has a single submit button on it when pressed it sends a get request to a PHP script. The PHP script creates a file called asdf.txt. At the moment I have this code on 2 different servers, one of which is Heroku. On Heroku this code works fine: a new file called asdf.txt is created. However, on the other server (the one I want to put this code on), this does not work. No error messages are present on the HTML page, however.

Ideally what I would like is to have some suggestions on how to debug this. If anything specific comes to mind please let me know however I am also interested in broadly any way to go about dealing with this problem. Thanks for your time.

Here is the PHP

```
<?php
system('echo asdf > asdf.txt', $retval);
?>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">


class NameForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }


    handleSubmit(){
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        }.bind(this)

        xmlHttp.open("GET","test.php",true)
        xmlHttp.send(null)
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div style={{fontSize: 30}}>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}><input style={{fontSize: 30}} type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NameForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: If it's working in one server and not working in other, in that case instead of looking client code, you need to check the server error logs to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, sometimes `system()`, `exec()` and their friends not giving us any error message. Even we set `display_erros` to `On`. As a workaround, I suggest you to create custom helper function like follow:

```
function my_exec($cmd, $input=''){
    $proc=proc_open($cmd, array(0=>array('pipe', 'r'), 1=>array('pipe', 'w'), 2=>array('pipe', 'w')), $pipes);
    fwrite($pipes[0], $input);fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);fclose($pipes[2]);
    $rtn=proc_close($proc);
    return array('stdout'=>$stdout,
        'stderr'=>$stderr,
        'return'=>$rtn
    );
}

var_export(my_exec('echo asdf > asdf.txt'));
```

I got those script from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#94929

Then you can check the result at your browser "Network inspector". But before guide you there, I feel there is something wrong with your `handleSubmit()` function. I believe it will not properly do `preventDefault()`. Because we working with React which by default it will have "Synthetic event". To properly do `preventDefault()` I believe, we should make it as follow:

```
handleSubmit(event){
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  }.bind(this)

  xmlHttp.open("GET","test.php",true)
  xmlHttp.send(null)
  event.nativeEvent.preventDefault();//This is how we really preventDefault() the native event, instead synthetic event
}
```

Then, after clicking "Submit", you should able to inspect the response from your PHP script.

[image: Browser inspect]

I suggest making `my_exec()` just as a helper function to debug. Once you feel it works properly, replace it back with `system()` or `exec()` or anything you like.